# PHP - When I click I want to go on an URL

Tags: php, url

this is the site: [www.matelelettronica.it](https://www.matelelettronica.it/catalogo/categorie/82-sicurezza/83-videosorveglianza/84-accessori/85-adattatori/291-adattatore-da-palo-generico-detail.html)

when you click: richiedi preventivo

you go on popup... I don't want this..
I want that when I click i want to go n a URL.

this is the actually code:

```
<?php
/**Let's see if we found the product */
if (empty ( $this->product )) {
    echo vmText::_ ( 'COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_NOT_FOUND' );
    echo '<br /><br />  ' . $this->continue_link_html;
} else {
    $session = JFactory::getSession();
    $sessData = $session->get('askquestion', 0, 'vm');
    if(!empty($this->login)){
        echo $this->login;
    }
    if(empty($this->login) or VmConfig::get('recommend_unauth',false)){
        ?>
        <div class="ask-a-question-view">
            <h1><?php echo vmText::_('COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_ASK_QUESTION')  ?></h1>

            <div class="product-summary">
                <div class="width70 floatleft">
                    <h2><?php echo $this->product->product_name ?></h2>
```

Comment: Don't post picture as code. Send your code as text

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: Comments on code please, which line is the line that produces the link, and which is the url you want to go to.

Comment: Where is the code of your link?